# pack_configure() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, tkinter

I actually don't know why it does this but something is wrong with root = Label(master,text =(click))
Label.pack()

but basically what this program does is simple its just a clicker game and thing is everything else works its just when im trying to add a counter to count how many clicks a user has clicked it doesnt work

```
from tkinter import *
import time
from tkinter import messagebox

master = Tk()

def uiPrint():
    info()
    print("")
    print(click)
    blankLine()
Label_1 = Label(text = "Double click purchases need 50 clicks!")
Label_1.pack()



click = 0
mult = 1
dcp1 = 0




def blankLine():
    for i in range(20):
        print("")

def purchaseDoubleClicksCommand():
    global click
    global mult
    if click < 50:
        messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "Not enough clicks!")
    elif click >= 5:
        mult = mult+1
        click = click - 50
        messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "Double Clicks Purchased!")

def buttonCommand():
    global click
    global mult
    click += 1*(mult)
    root = Label(master,text =(click))
    Label.pack()


mainClickButton = Button(master, text="Click!", command = buttonCommand)
mainClickButton.pack()
    
purchaseDoubleClickButton = Button(master, text="Purchase Double Clicks", command = purchaseDoubleClicksCommand)
purchaseDoubleClickButton.pack()


    

master.title("Clicker!")
master.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (400,100,512,512))
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are calling an instance method without an active instance:

```
Label.pack()
```

It is only possible for methods that are callable from the class itself and doesn't require an active instance/object e.g. methods decorated with `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod`. Thus change it to:

```
root.pack()
```

With the instance `root`, the `self` argument would automatically be passed as first argument, which references the `root` object itself.

Comment: but how do i do this then       the numbers stack under each other isnt there a thing to delete the previous number ?

Comment: @FlamingBlizzard: That sounds like a question you should ask separately, since it's unrelated to the issue you had calling the `pack` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use root.pack() instead of Label.pack()

Comment: Seem to be the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/69286184/9193372

Comment: An answer which basically proposes the same solution as an existing answer can theoretically still be a valuable contribution, if it explains more, or from a different angle, or more understandably... But this post does not. Please do not expect users to find this post helpful.